# Длинный переход в ARM

Tags: ассемблер, arm

В процессорах ARM Thumb инструкция `B` даёт возможность перехода только на ограниченное смещение. Поэтому компилятор IAR при переходе исполнения от flash-памяти к оперативной памяти генерирует дополнительный код, с помощью которого это ограничение обходится, и называется этот код Veneer. Вот пример дизассемблера:

```
;Veneer (6) for flashPageEraseInfo:
LDR PC, [PC, #0x0]
.word 0x200067c9 ;flashPageEraseInfo
```

Почему в команде LDR указано смещение 0, а не 4? Ведь адрес, на который нужно перейти, находится в следующей за `PC` ячейке памяти.

Странно ещё то, что при пошаговой трассировке этот код выполняется, и программа переходит по нужному адресу, а при обычном выполнении происходит HardFault. Может быть здесь нужно добавлять барьер? Но я не знаю, как настроить компилятор для этого.

Comment: В момент _выполнения_ инструкции РС уже инкрементирован и указывает на след.слово. Про остальное ничего не могу подсказать..

Comment: Добавив барьеры DSB и ISB в С-коде перед вызовом функции `flashPageEraseInfo`, то есть за две инструкции до указанного фрагмента кода, я избавился от проблемы. Проблема исчезает только при парном использовании барьеров и только в этом порядке.